# ASP.NET and jQuery remove button permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a link with button behavior (bootstrap built-in) that i need to remove once it's clicked.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" type="button" href="#default">Home Page</a>
```

Currently i am using jQuery to remove the button e.g.

```
var btn = $('.btn');
btn.remove();
```

Actually this works just fine except that if you refresh the page the button as you guess it present on the page again. I want to remove it permanently though not sure if it's doable on the client side.

The project is an ASP.NET one-page web app.

Thank you

Comment: Avoid doing a full postback as that is causing the html to get served again. If you can try using an asynchronous call to do the operations that you want.

Comment: I am afraid i cannot make the visitors don't click the refresh button and cause a full postback. Meaning that's the reason why i need solution because they can always hit refresh and see the same button again which is what i don't want to happens. How can i remove that button permanently? I would like to avoid AJAX if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` should help in this:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" type="button" href="#default">Home Page</a>


$('.btn').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hmm if i add preventDefault the button does not work at all so the default div is not getting visible. This is a full screen one-page design so when this button is called i expect another page to gets loaded. Thx

Comment: @ElizabethDimova How about `return false;` instead of that line?

Comment: Nope it didn't work for me either. Thank you for the suggestions anyway